# Using one function as an optional argument in another function

Tags: python, function, optional-parameters

Say I've got this function (a very simple function just to get my point across):

```
def f(x):
    if x:
         return(True)
    return(False)
```

Now I want to use this function as an optional argument in another function, e.g. I tried something like this:

```
def g(x, f_out = f(x)):
    return(f_out)
```

So basically if I did `g(1)` the output should be `True`, and if I did `g(0)` I want the output to be `False`, as `f(0)` is `False` and thus `f_out` is `False`.

When I try this though, `f_out` is always `True` regardless of `x`. How can I make it such that the function `f` is actually called when getting the value `f_out`?

The code that I'm actually using this principle on is obviously more complicated but it's the same idea; I have an optional argument in some `function1` that calls a different `function2` with parameters which are already parameters in `function1`, e.g. `x` in my example. (Sorry I'm aware that's perhaps an unclear way of explaining.)

Answer (score 3):

You're calling the function `f_out` in the declaration. You want to pass the function itself as a parameter, and call it inside `g`:

```
def g(x, f_out=f):
    return f_out(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

`f_out = f(x)` attempts to call `f()` at the time that the function is declared (which fails without a global `x` defined), not when it is invoked. Try this instead:

```
def g(x, f_out=f):
    return f_out(x)
```

This calls `f()` with argument `x` and returns its value from `g()`.